# Volume is already exclusively attached to one node and can't be attached to another

Tags: kubernetes, kops, statefulset

I have a pretty simple Kubernetes pod. I want a stateful set and want the following process:

1. I want to have an initcontainer download and uncompress a tarball from s3 into a volume mounted to the initcontainer
2. I want to mount that volume to my main container to be used

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: app
  namespace: test
  labels:
    name: app
spec:
  serviceName: app
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: preparing
        image: alpine:3.8
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        command:
          - "sh"
          - "-c"
          - |
            echo "Downloading data"
            wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/.........
            tar -xvzf xxxx-........ -C /root/
        volumeMounts:
        - name: node-volume
          mountPath: /root/data/

      containers:
      - name: main-container
        image: ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/image/:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always

        volumeMounts:
        - name: node-volume
          mountPath: /root/data/

  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: node-volume
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: gp2-b
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 80Gi
```

I continue to get the following error:

At first I run this and I can see the logs flowing of my tarball being downloaded by the initcontainer. About half way done it terminates and gives me the following error:

```
Multi-Attach error for volume "pvc-faedc8" Volume is 
already exclusively attached to one node and can't be 
attached to another
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using emptyDir type of volume?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looks like you have a dangling [PVC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#persistentvolumeclaims) and/or [PV](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) that is attached to one of your nodes.  You can ssh into the node and run a `df` or `mount` to check.

If you look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46442238/can-i-rely-on-volumeclaimtemplates-naming-convention) the PVCs in a StatefulSet are always mapped to their pod names, so it may be possible that you still have a dangling pod(?)

If you have a dangling pod:

```
$ kubectl -n test delete pod <pod-name>
```

You may have to force it:

```
$ kubectl -n test delete pod <pod-name> --grace-period=0 --force
```

Then, you can try deleting the PVC and it's corresponding PV:

```
$ kubectl delete pvc pvc-faedc8
$ kubectl delete pv <pv-name>
```

Comment: I would suggest to clean up dangling pod before you go ahead and delete PV and PVC

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've added an updated to the answer

Answer (score 8):

Here is the ONLY solution that worked for me:

1. Scale your app to `0`

```bash
kubectl -n NAMESPACE scale deployment/stateful NAME --replicas 0
```

or

```bash
kubectl -n NAMESPACE edit deployment/stateful NAME
```

And manually edit `replicas: 0`

---

Delete all `volumeattachment`:

```bash
kubectl -n NAMESPACE delete volumeattachment --all
```

---

Bring back the replicas.

That's it

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue right now and the problem was, that the node on which the pod is usually running on was down and another one took over (which didn't work as expected for whatever reason). Had the "node down" scenario a few times before already and it never caused any issues. Couldn't get the StatefulSet and Deployment back up and running without booting the node that was down. But as soon as the node was up and running again the StatefulSet and Deployment immediately came back to life as well.

Comment: same here. updated my node pool to the latest version and some pods with PVCs were stuck in this error afterwards. There has to be a different way, other than deleting the volume!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error:

```
 The volume pvc-2885ea01-f4fb-11eb-9528-00505698bd8b 
   cannot be attached to the node node1 since it is already attached to the node node2*
```

I use longhorn as a storage provisioner and manager. So I just detached this pv in the error and restarted the stateful set. It automatically was able to attach to the pv correctly this time.

Answer (score -2):

I'll add an answer that will prevent this from happening again.

#### Short answer

[Access modes](https://here): Switch from `ReadWriteOnce` to `ReadWriteMany`.

---

#### In a bit more details

You're usng a StatefulSet where each replica has its own state, with a unique persistent volume claim (PVC) created for each pod.
Each PVC is referring to a Persistent Volume where you decided that **the access mode is `ReadWriteOnce`.**

Which as you can see from [here](https://%20accessModes:%20%5B%20%22ReadWriteOnce%22%20%5D):

> **ReadWriteOnce** 
> the volume can be mounted as read-write **by a single
> node**. ReadWriteOnce access mode still can allow multiple pods to
> access the volume when the pods are running on the same node.

So in case K8S Scheduler (due to priorities or resource calculations or due to a Cluster autoscaler which decided to shift the pod to a different node) - you will receive an error that the volume is already exclusively attached to one node and can't be
attached to another node.

Please consider using `ReadWriteMany` where the volume can be mounted as read-write by many nodes.