# How do I connect a helm package to a PersistentStorage volume?

Tags: kubernetes, redis, kubernetes-helm, persistent-storage, docker-desktop

I've seen this question come up often, and I've yet to find a clean, generic solution. I'm just learning Kubernetes so maybe there's something basic I'm missing. But here's what I've done:

1. install docker-desktop with kubernetes
2. manually create a persistent-storage volume using a yaml file (shown below)
3. `helm install redis dandydev/redis-ha`

Or you can use any other helm chart, be it elasticsearch, postgres, you name it. I always get `pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims`.

Also when I run: `kubectl get storageclasses.storage.k8s.io`
I do have (default) storage:

```
NAME                 PROVISIONER          AGE
hostpath (default)   docker.io/hostpath   3h8m
```

Can anyone please help me fix this issue in a generic way? So that I can actually install helm charts and have them automatically connect to a persistent storage volume?

My volume.yaml:

```yaml
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: redis-volume
  labels:
    type: local
    app: redis
spec:
  storageClassName: ""
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/redis"
```

Comment: In redis helm chart code you can see [this code](https://github.com/DandyDeveloper/charts/blob/master/charts/redis-ha/templates/redis-ha-statefulset.yaml#L286-L316) that suggests you may want to read [my other answer to simmilar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62238476/how-to-extract-volumeclaimtemplates-to-a-separate-persistentvolumeclaim-yaml-fil/62263046#62263046). Let me know if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I looked more online among the various custom solutions, and one did work:
https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/12521#issuecomment-477834805

In addition this answer provides more details into how to enable dynamic provisioning locally:
[pod has unbound PersistentVolumeClaims](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52668938/pod-has-unbound-persistentvolumeclaims)

Basically (in addition to having the volume created above) I need to manually:

1. create a storage class, via storage-class.yaml
2. add that storage class to helm in 'values.yaml'

```yaml
# storage-class.yaml
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: data-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

In addition, some charts running locally need you to customize their config, under `<your-helm>/charts/<chart-name>/<file-to-config.yaml>`, or via `--set <var>=value`since, most helm charts want you to use more nodes, and running locally you might only have a single node.

Another option is to use `helm install --set replicas=1 ...` and some charts will work well with this.

Hope this helps someone out there.